# D3 function for gauge-like scale to produce: [-2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 2]

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Which d3 scale function or method do I use to transform data

`input = 13 // count of items to be had in an array`

into an array where:

- the middle value is 0,
- left-side values are descending,
- and right-side values are ascending

`output = [-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] // 13 items`

I bet there is an elegant solution yet I do not speak data science language to find it myself.

Items count can be even, then the middle is twice 0:

`input = 6 // count of items to be had in an array`

`output = [-2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 2] // 6 items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a D3 scale: a D3 scale maps an input value (domain) to an output value (range).

As you explained, you just want to convert a number *N* into an array of *N* elements following a given rule. That said, you just need a function that generates the array, which can be done with `d3.range` (or even with plain JS, no D3 needed).

For instance:

```js
function gauge(input) {
  return d3.range(input--).map(d => ~~(d - input / 2));
};

console.log(gauge(13))
console.log(gauge(6))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And here the plain JS version, no D3:

```js
function gauge(input) {
  return Array.from(Array(input--).keys()).map(d => ~~(d - input / 2));
};

console.log(gauge(13))
console.log(gauge(6))
```